# Python fetchall return true and false

Tags: python, fetchall

I have a python script that makes a fetchall():

```
connection = pymssql.connect(host='host', user='user', password='pw', database='database', as_dict=True)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("EXEC SPname")
data=cursor.fetchall()
```

My problem is that the cursor.fetchall() is returning True or Falses (and others columns with others values example above) but in the database the value is a bit 1 or 0 and when exported to CSV it puts the True or False and I want 1 or 0.

Sample data returned in SQL:

```
ID      Price       Price2      Price3      Active      Opened      Sent        Enable
1      12234.09     1111.09    3444.36      1           1           1           0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `int()`

**Ex:**

```
print(int(True))
print(int(False))
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. The problem is that the SP returns multiple columns, in this case 88, and I dont want to explicitly designates them because it has a lot of columns and I want something dynamic because if I alter the SP to return one more column I don't want to alter the script to add the column.

The objective is next do the this:
`a= csv.writer(fp, delimiter=';')
    for line in data:
        a.writerows(line)`

Comment: You do not need to alter the SP, instead modify the bool value right before writing to the csv file.

Comment: Correct but that implies that i make:
`a= csv.writer(fp, delimiter=';')
    for line in data:
        line["mycolumn1"] = int(line["mycolumn1"]) 
        line["mycolumn2"] = int(line["mycolumn2"]) 
        line["mycolumn3"] = int(line["mycolumn3"])
         a.writerows(line)`
And this take a lots of time and if I had a new bit value in the SP I have to add another condition in the script

Comment: Can you post a sample of `data`?

Comment: `line = [True, 12234.09, 1111.09, 3444.36, True, True, True, False]
print( [int(i) if isinstance(i, bool) else i for i in line] )` ?

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples or dictionaries. The easiest way to convert them to integers is by mapping the `int` method to that list:

```
data_in_integer_form = map(int, data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but the data returned is not only booleans it's also decimal, strings, etc..

Comment: Well, that's a different question than the one stated in the first place. You said the query was returning True and False, not decimals and strings.